# Array prototype clarification

Tags: javascript

Here's the code:

```
var o ={};

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(o) == Object.prototype); // returns true as expected

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Array) == Array.prototype); // returns false why?
```

Could someone please clarify the second result?

Comment: Because `Array` is not an instantiated instance of an Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var a=[];
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a) == Array.prototype);
```

You're using the `Array` type itself, instead of an instance of it.

Answer (score 4):

because Array is not an 'array' but the Prototype of Array
but with this example :

```
var a = [];
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a) == Array.prototype);
```

It works